# Rebooting an EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm working on a project involving EC2 and I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around this concept.

With EC2 instances, will non-EBS backed volumes (standard EC2) survive a reboot of the OS?  For example, I have an Ubuntu instance.  If I type `/sbin/shutdown -r now`, will I lose all data on the drive not in the AMI?  I understand that if I terminate the instance via the tools or the control panel, I lose everything, but I can't find a concrete answer to the restart issue.

An extra gold star goes to anyone who can  link to documentation clearly explaining this. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your data will stay the same between simple reboots.

Here is a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637790/what-happens-when-i-reboot-an-ec2-instance) with the same answer.

In the [EC2 FAQ](https://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1145), see the "what happens to my data when my instance terminates" question. It has a note that covers this.